# GWT CKEditor with Selenium

Tags: gwt, selenium, ckeditor

I am using **GWT-CKEditor** for my application. And I want to test it through **selenium**. But I am not able to find the target parameter for Ckeditor in selenium. I am not able to locate it in Selenium. How can I acheive this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following command in Selenium IDE to record this..

```
focus | class=html-editor portlet portlet-message-boards cke_show_borders

typeKeys | class=html-editor portlet portlet-message-boards cke_show_borders | Description
```

In above command, class=html-editor portlet portlet-message-boards cke_show_borders is the class id of that CKEditor of my application so please check GWT-CKEditor class id using firebug.